# Jquery .val() changes the value in dom but not on web page

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a block of debug code MyPartialContent.ascx: (returned from an jquery ajax call and inserted into DOM with $("#container").val(html); where html is the code block below

```
 <input type"text" id="mydebugtextbox" value="world"/> -- shows a text box on web page with "world"
```

---

```
$("#mydebugtextbox").val("hello"); 
-- Should set value to "hello";

alert($("#mydebugtextbox").val()); 
-- should alert "hello" and it does but 
-- the textbox on the page still shows "world"
```

This only happens when the page is initially loaded. If I hit f5 or refresh the page then everything works as expected.

I am lost.

Comment: Can we see your full code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there's only 1 **input box** with that ID in your whole DOM page?
if you have 2 input boxes, only the 1st one is going to be updated

See this sample,
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/hMqSq/

---

prev answer...

Supposing there are no spelling errors and you are putting your code on page load

```
$(function() {  
//code here
});
```

Are you sure you dont have a plugin that autocomplete your input box?
What browser are you using?

Comment: I had multiple instances of the textbox in the DOM with same ID.

Comment: ah yes, that happens too. it could be caused by the way the elements are cloned/insert to the dom. you could go for a class instead of id if you want. $('input.class').val()

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/azifav/1/edit)*

simply change 
`mydegugtextbox` to

`mydebugtextbox`

And if your syntax is correct make sure to wrap your code into a `ready` function:

```
$(function(){ // DOM is ready

     $("#mydebugtextbox").val("hello");
     alert($("#mydebugtextbox").val()); 

});
```

to make sure your element is mapped and ready to be manipulated

Comment: the structure and flow of the my jscript is more complicated than that.. I have a file Logic.js that is loaded in the site.master <head> when the partialview is loaded after an ajax call. I do something like Logic.doSomething();

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you misspelled `debug` in your first selector:

```
$("#mydegugtextbox").val("hello");
        ^
```

Once you fix that typo, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/NMFEs/1/

Comment: @magic-c0d3r: Is this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: nto really it is in a partialview (.ascx)

Comment: @magic-c0d3r: IIRC, ASP is serverside. You still need to wrap your jQuery-enabled code in a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: have you done MVC and used partial views? I need the script executed when the partialview is inserted into the DOM. This happens after the ajax call and I do $("#container").html(data);

Comment: @magic-c0d3r: I don't work with ASP, so I'm not familiar with the terminology.